# use data from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I using self host api and want to use the data from the ajax call in another function, but it does not work. I get undefinded.

My Code:

```
function checkData() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/Data"
}).success(function (result) {
    var datareturned = result.stateLog;
    console.log('done' + datareturned);
    x = datareturned;
    test(x);
});
}

setInterval(checkData, 5000);

function test(data) {
alert(data); // Here i get undefined
}
```

Do you know how can I use the data?

Comment: put the `test(data)` inside `checkData()` and try again

Comment: does your console.log show the correct `datareturned`?

Comment: it will work. Can u pls give fiddle code

Comment: @Pekka he has `test(x)` inside `success` of `checkData-ajax`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao sorry i didnt see the `text(x)` part.

Comment: i tried making a fiddle and just using a set data i should work so something else is making the error check this http://jsfiddle.net/0mu1qgsf/

Answer (score 1):

I try this and Work fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function checkData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "file.data.txt"
            }).success(function (result) {
                console.log('readed:' + JSON.stringify(result));    
                var datareturned = JSON.parse(result).stateLog;
                console.log('done ' + datareturned);
                var x = datareturned;
                test(x);
            });
        }

        setInterval(checkData, 5000);

        function test(data) {
            alert(data); // Here i get undefined
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

JSON DATA(file.data.txt):

```
{
"stateLog":"Active"

}
```

Comment: hmm, i did not really get it. I have a as url not data.txt file. It is a adress.

Comment: @trap your url does not seem to return any useable data, please check what your console.log call puts into your console.

Answer (score 0):

in the console.log it still comes undefined.

But if i change the code like that:

```
{
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/Data",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});}
```

I get a console log (an object)

Comment: try to change console.log(data) to console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); and post console.log result

Answer (score 0):

Your result object does not seem to have a .stateLog property. If you are trying to access the html response status, you might want

```
.success(function (result, response) {
    var datareturned = result;
    console.log('done' + response);
    x = datareturned;
    test(x);
}
```

Or

```
.success(function (result, response, jqXHR) {
    var datareturned = result;
    console.log('done' + jqXHR.statusCode);
    x = datareturned;
    test(x);
}
```

Or something like that.
If you try to return an Object as your result which ought to have a .stateLog property, then you should specify the dataType of the Ajax calls and/or make sure your server returns the correct format. e.g. if you return a json string, you need to parse it first before you can use it as an object.
Of course the object then needs to have the desired property.

Comment: Yes, I had not the right property. It is working now! Thanks!